# Check character containment in a string

Tags: c#

I am doing a homework question to split a string. I have a doubt in that.

```
string text = "my text";
char[] delim = new char[]{' '};
```

How can I check if `text[i]` is in `delim`, without having code iteration?

```
if(text[i] in delim) //not correct
{
}
```

Comment: Look at [the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) and see if there's any methods in there that could help you.

Comment: By "without having code iteration" do you mean without using loops?

Comment: It seems like there is something mixed up in your source code. Shouldn't you write:  

**if (delim[i] in text)**  

(Thats just for clarification of the question, the postet code won't work either)

Comment: I am iterating the source string char by char and checking if it is part of delim char array. If it not I'm adding to a StringBuilder. else I add the StringBuilder buffer to result string array and reinitialize  buffer.

Comment: I know there are built in methods for string spilt, but I'm supposed to use minimum built in code and deal in char as much as possible

Comment: I got the feeling that no one acually understands your question (me neither) - maybe you should edit the question and try to make it easier to understand for us.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you don't have any choice then to iterate through the original string. Or you could try to write a recursive method.

Answer (score 0):

`string` has a member named `Contains`.  Is  this what you are looking for?

Here is the link to the MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this:

```
        string text = "my text";
        string[] txtSplit = null;
        if (text.Contains(" "))
        {
            txtSplit = text.Split(' ');
        }
```

Please Mark as answered if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the different words in a string.
In that case I would recommend to use the Split-method.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx